# Custom CRUD Stored Procedures using Code First

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I've been using EF6 code-first approach on a new project, and it has been wonderful, but now I struggling a bit on how to customized the CRUD stored procedures, so that some columns are computed in the database.

Process (abstract):

```
public abstract class Process
{
    public int Id {get; set}
    public int Name {get; set}
    public DateTime CreateDate{get; private set}
    public DateTime UpdateDate{get; private set}

    public virtual ICollection<ProcessContact> Contacts { get; set; }
}
```

ProcessContact:

```
public class ProcessContact
{
    public string Name {get; set}
    public string Value {get; set}
}
```

ProcessA:

```
public class ProcessA: Process
{
    public int A {get; set}
}
```

ProcessB:

```
public class ProcessB: Process
{
    public int B {get; set}
}
```

Given the 3 classes above as an example how can I in EF6 code-first, customized the generated stored procedure so it can for example:

- On insert of `Process`, set the `Id` as `count(*)+1` and `CreateDate = GETUTCTIME()`
- On update of `ProcessContact`, set `UpdateDate = GETUTCTIME()` in the `Process` table

Comment: Procedural code is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Why would you do this in DB? Then you are back to specific prodedural code. As it is code first, I manage this in code..

Comment: I am not sure if you can modify the generated stored procédure, pretty sure you can. If not, just copy it and then modify it. Then EF has the option to map to an existing stored procedure. I dont even know why you are using stored procédure (there are times when it makes sense to use them).

Comment: Are you aware of the Key attribute and the injection of values when saving/updating?

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback. I´ve added the tag. Regarding the Key for using an identity in my case I want them to be sequential (identity doesn't guarantee that) and on another case i didnt place here it must be computed. On the question of the datetime its to use the server datetime instead of the desktop. I don´t doubt your expertise, but to be honest I don´t get whats the problem on setting some values at the database. I understand that changing DB will cause me to rewrite the stored procedures.

Comment: Your code will break the moment a record other than the last one gets deleted, not to mention deadlocks and/or concurrency issues. It may not be a requirement today, but you can expect at some point in it's production life to have to perform a data correction. For setting things like UpdateDates, keep it simple and handle that in code. A ProcessContact should have a reference back to the Process so when your repository/service goes to persist it, check dirty state and update the related Process.